# An awk script to run over different files

Tags: bash, awk

I have wrote this script: **looking.awk** that searches for particular data in a file:

```
 {if ($0 ~ "NEIGHBORS OF THE NON-EQUIVALENT ATOMS") {FLAG=1}};
 # If the current line of the file begins with that string, we asign it a FLAG=1

    {if (FLAG==1)
            {if ($0 ~ $1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==14 && $7=="O"){LINE=$0;
            exit}
            }
    };
    # Here I am searching for "1 CA" on each line

 END{VOL=FILENAME;
 # The filename is: "c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out"
 # My intention is to end up with a new file with 2 columns:
 # "volume" and "distance". 
 # Notice that the filename contains the volume: 273.008245

 gsub("^.*_V_","",VOL);
 gsub("_",".",VOL);
 gsub(".50.neighbours.SYMREMO.out"," ",VOL);
 # Some substitutions to make "c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out" 
 # to be "273.008245"

 # Up to now the output of running: 
 # search_for_distance.awk -f c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out
 # is the following:

 # 273.008245     1 CA   1     2.4055     4.5458    7 O    0 0 0

 # So, I need to take LINE and only extract column "4".
 # This is done by a "split" command:

 {split(LINE,array," ")}   

 print VOL,array[4]}
```

The script is located in the current folder `.`

I have several folders and files in which I'd like to run this script.

These are the ***paths***:

```
 .../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_247_803181/c_V_247_803181_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out

 .../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_250_532893/c_V_247_803181_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out

 .
 .
 .
```

I am running the script as:

```
 awk -f looking.awk ../CVOLOPTs*_V*/calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out > ./d_Ca-1_O_7/data.dat
```

But in the `data.dat` generated there is only the result of the script over the `.../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_247_803181/c_V_247_803181_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out` file

How can I run the script so that it looks inside all the `.out` files that are in those ***paths***?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What is the expansion of `../CVOLOPTs*_V*/calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out`? That is, what do you get if you say `ls -l ../CVOLOPTs*_V*/calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out`? Because your approach seems to be fine.

Comment: `{if ($0 ~ "^   1 CA"){LINE=$0;
            exit}` this exits the script and will not process any more files.

Comment: @fedorqui   `ls -l ../CVOLOPTs*_V*/calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out` gives 11 `.out` files: `../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_247_803181/calcite_IIIb_optimization_bulk_optimised_more_wall_time_EOS_analysis_NEW_RUN_FROM_V_247_803181_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out`, `../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_250_532893/calcite_IIIb_optimization_bulk_optimised_more_wall_time_EOS_analysis_NEW_RUN_FROM_V_250_532893_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out`, `../CVOLOPTs_and_f9_for_labels_V_252_862706/calcite_IIIb_optimization_bulk_optimised_more_wall_time_EOS_analysis_NEW_RUN_FROM_V_252_862706_50_neighgours_SYMREMO.out` `...`

Comment: @123 Ok, thanks, +1! there is the problem, how could I make the script to look to the other files? Thanks again

Comment: Do you have gawk 4+ ?

Comment: @123 Yes, I have `GNU Awk 4.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I run the script so that it looks inside all the .out files
>   that are in those paths?

```
find /base/directory/to/search -type f -name "*.out" -exec awk -f /path/to/looking.awk {} >>/path/to/d_Ca-1_O_7/data.dat \;
```

**What is happening here?**

1. We set `/base/directory/to/search` as the base directory to search.
2. We ask `find` to find files by the `type` directive.
3. We wish to look for all files ending with `.out` so we set the name to `*.out`. The `*` here is a wild-card that will expand to all possible outputs which we filter using criteria we already mentioned in 1 & 2.
4. `-exec` is used to apply commands on the filtered output. This is just a pipe which help you process the output of find. But at the same time it is different from normal pipe (`|`) in that the formatting applied by `find` -say `-print0` - is retained by exec. Formatting is done in cases where we process non-standard files,for example, files with new-lines or special characters. We use `{}` to pass the formatted string to the command.
5. We do the `awk` stuff and append the results to the `dat` file.

Comment: I have tried: `find . -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name "./d_Ca-1_O_7/data.dat" -exec awk -f search_for_minimum_distances_new.awk {} >>./d_Ca-1_O_7/d_Ca-1_O_7.dat \;` but it does not work, it prints the name of the script in `./d_Ca-1_O_7/d_Ca-1_O_7.dat`

Comment: @DavidC. You don't need `-not -name` if you put `-name "*.out"`. I edited the script.

Comment: @sjsamThank you very much, this worked! +1! But, could you please explain the syntax? I am still learning and this is quite hard... 1) What does `-mindepth 1` mean? 2) Does `-type f` tells to the `awk` script that he has to look in files? 3) Why `-exec awk -f` and not simply `awk` ? 3) Why do you add a `{}` after the script name? 4) why a `\;` after the output file? If you could update the answer with this information it would clarify a lot... again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Regarding `-mindepth`, it is not required in your case as your looking for `files`. But when you search for directories, a minimum depth of one will exclude the `/path/that/you/search` from coming in the results.To understand the results try both of these `find . -mindepth 1 -type d` and  `find . -type d`

Comment: Thanks! +1! Now is clear that the `exec` "pipe" has to be stopped by `\;`

Comment: Now, I understand that since I am looking for files, I can omit the `-mindepth 1`. BUT, the command should be `find ../CVOLOPTs*_V*/ -type f -name "calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out" -exec awk -f search_for_minimum_distances_new_Ca-1_O_7.awk {} >>./data \;`  and not the following command you suggested in the 12-May comment: `find ../CVOLOPTs*_V*/ -type d -name "calcite_IIIb*V*50_n*_SYMREMO.out" -exec awk -f search_for_minimum_distances_new_Ca-1_O_7.awk {} >>./data \;`

Comment: Well May 12th comment was just for you to understand the difference between `find /some/where -mindepth 1` and `find /some/where` . Not meant to try in your problem . In fact I never suggested you to use `-type d` here..

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! Ahm, I understand... so when you look for files, you have to use `find . -type f` or, you can also use (it is not necessary) the minimum depth as `find . -mindepth 1 -type f`. Therefore, when the `find . -mindepth 1 -type d` should be used? When you want to execute the `.awk` script in a directory? (this would never be a case, right?)

Answer (score 2):

`exit`, predictably, causes Awk to exit; so you stop processing after the first match on `CA`.

I'm guessing perhaps you are looking for [`nextfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) which, as you might guess, skips to the next file in the list of input files. (Note that this is a relatively recent addtion to the language; if you are using a legacy Awk, maybe upgrade, or switch to GNU Awk.)

Of course, `END` only happens at the end of input; I'm guessing the stuff in the current `END` block should happen just before `nextfile` instead, to produce one result per input file.

Tangentially, your script is extremely unidiomatic.  The default scope of regex matching is `$0` so anything that looks like

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ "moo") ...}'
```

should probably be written simply as

```
awk '/moo/ { ... }'
```

Also, if all you ever care about is `$4` out of `LINE`, simply replace

```
LINE=$0
```

with

```
FIELD=$4
```

to avoid having to split the line back to an array in the `END` block just to extract the fourth field.

You also have a weird syntax error in `if ($0 ~ $1==1)` which I *think* is not what you want to say.  Brief testing indicates that this evaluates `$1==1` for truth and then compares the input line to the result of this comparison (a truth value which is either 0 or 1).  I'm guessing you left in the `$0 ~` by mistake.

Wrapping up, and noting that we are guessing a good deal here, the script you are looking for might be something like

```
awk '/NEIGHBORS OF THE NON-EQUIVALENT ATOMS/ {FLAG=1}
  FLAG==1 && $1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==14 && $7=="O" {
      VOL=FILENAME;
      gsub("^.*_V_","",VOL); gsub("_",".",VOL);  gsub(".50.neighbours.SYMREMO.out"," ",VOL);
      print VOL, $4;
      nextfile }' list of file names here ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed the `{if ($0 ... ...` part of the script, because it has to look for a more specific search. Updated the script in the question. I'm afraid I cannot change this, because this works well. Perhaps later I can follow your instructions on `awk '{ if ($0 ~ "moo") ...}'` and so on and rewrite the script in a less "unidiomatic" way... but for the moment the most important thing is to make this script to look for the other files. I have looked the link you posted on `nextfile` but I cannot find the way to use it...

Comment: Could you please post a code to replace the `exit` with the `nextfile` command? thanks a lot, +1

Comment: Extracting the interesting value out of the file name is still somewhat ugly.  I would probably use `split()` on underscore for that instead if the number of fields in the file name is predictable.

Comment: nitpick - unless it's called in the END section, `exit` doesn't actually cause awk to exit, it causes awk to go to the `END` section (try `awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"; exit} END{print "bar"}'`). It's just a detail that can bite you once in a while.